# Redirect from any component to another page in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

Hello im new on af and I´m trying to redirect by clicking on any adf component to another page. But i dont want to use javascript only with adf and beans.

I have been looking for something similar to the onclick of javascript that you can use it on any html element and with a click you can invoke a function.
On my test i had tried to redirect to another page by clicking on a af:inputText like when i click on an af:link and execute the action with the name of the control flow case for navigate from one activity to another, looking on the documentation, the af:inputText doesn´t have any onclick/action event or something similar.

primera.jsff

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">

    <!--af:link When i click on it i get redirected to another jsff page on my project -->
    <af:link text="link 1" id="link1" action="gonext"></af:link>
    <!--I want a similar behavior here -->
    <af:inputText label="Label 1" id="it1"/>

</ui:composition>
```

My task-flow has defined a control flow case from primera.jsff to a empty segunda.jsff named gonext

I just want the similar behavior on the af:inputText than on the af:link, but only using adf not javascript code. Thanks and sorry for the redaction.

Comment: You’ll need custom JS if you want to navigate using components, like inputText, that were designed NOT to have an action.

Comment: Why not use JS as intended and designed and like everyone else does? There are *many* examples of using JS in ADF via google and it is *very* easy to do. It's a common practice when people want the ADF Faces framework to do things (and that goes for JSF as well ) that it was not intended to do.